# OrderBy is not working on "name" property for OneDrive Business SharedWithMe items

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

As per the OneDrive specs, OneDrive Business supports sorting only on name field. However, when I am trying to OrderBy "name" on SharedWithMe items, it throws exception as "Sorting on 'name' isn't supported.". I am using below code from Microsoft Graph SDK for OrderBy on name field:

```
var response = await client.Me.Drive.SharedWithMe().Request().OrderBy("name").GetAsync();
```

I have also verified this using the API HTTP Get call, but didn't have any luck. Needed to perform sorting in SharedWithMe items.

Answer (score 1):

The SharedWithMe api for OneDrive for Business currently only supports sorting based on the following properties:

- lastModifiedDateTime
- lastModifiedBy

Sorting based on name should however be supported by the Search API. I will get the docs updated.

Comment: I was able to sort on "lastModifiedDateTime" field. However, sort on "lastModifiedBy" field threw error as "The $orderby expression must evaluate to a single value of primitive type."